# Using Cassandra JDBC-compliant driver with DataNucleus JDO

Tags: cassandra, jdo, datanucleus

I'm considering to use [JDBC-compliant driver](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-jdbc/) with JDO to connecto to Cassandra. Is this possible and is this going to cause huge overhead? I was looking [astyanax](https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax) made by Netflix, and it looks good, but it is not easy as JDO seems to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using a JDBC driver you need to write an RDBMS adapter class for Cassandra to communicate with it (see the DN docs).

Alternatively use a Cassandra plugin for DataNucleus https://github.com/pulasthi/Datanucleus-Cassandra-Plugin
Note that this plugin was not provided by the DataNucleus project (so some things in it may be non-optimal due the people concerned not necessarily understanding how a store plugin ought to be written) and only works for DataNucleus v2.x.

*Update [Jan 2014]* : there is now an official DataNucleus Cassandra plugin under development, already providing many things, and using CQL3

Answer (score 1):

The Cassandra CQL JDBC driver is located at http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-jdbc/